# What is the reason of this differences in the three expressions in Surat Al-Kahf 79 - 82?

Tags: quran, arabic, surat-al-kahf

Allah says in Surat Al-Kahf in aya 79:

> أَمَّا السَّفِينَةُ فَكَانَتْ لِمَسَاكِينَ يَعْمَلُونَ فِي الْبَحْرِ
>   **فَأَرَدتُّ** أَنْ أَعِيبَهَا وَكَانَ وَرَاءَهُم مَّلِكٌ يَأْخُذُ كُلَّ سَفِينَةٍ غَصْبًا
>
> As for the ship, it belonged to poor people working at sea. So **I
>   intended** to cause defect in it as there was after them a king who
>   seized every [good] ship by force

then in the next aya :

> وَأَمَّا الْغُلَامُ فَكَانَ أَبَوَاهُ مُؤْمِنَيْنِ **فَخَشِينَا**
>   أَن يُرْهِقَهُمَا طُغْيَانًا وَكُفْرًا، **فَأَرَدْنَا** أَن
>   يُبْدِلَهُمَا رَبُّهُمَا خَيْرًا مِّنْهُ زَكَاةً وَأَقْرَبَ رُحْمًا
>
> And as for the boy, his parents were believers, and **we feared** that he
>   would overburden them by transgression and disbelief, So **we
>   intended** that their Lord should substitute for them one better than
>   him in purity and nearer to mercy

then:

> وَأَمَّا الْجِدَارُ فَكَانَ لِغُلَامَيْنِ يَتِيمَيْنِ فِي الْمَدِينَةِ
>   وَكَانَ تَحْتَهُ كَنزٌ لَّهُمَا وَكَانَ أَبُوهُمَا صَالِحًا 
>   **فَأَرَادَ رَبُّكَ** أَن يَبْلُغَا أَشُدَّهُمَا وَيَسْتَخْرِجَا كَنزَهُمَا رَحْمَةً مِّن رَّبِّكَ ۚ وَمَا فَعَلْتُهُ عَنْ أَمْرِي ۚ
>   ذَٰلِكَ تَأْوِيلُ مَا لَمْ تَسْطِع عَّلَيْهِ صَبْرًا
>
> And as for the wall, it belonged to two orphan boys in the city, and
>   there was beneath it a treasure for them, and their father had been
>   righteous. So **your Lord intended** that they reach maturity and
>   extract their treasure, as a mercy from your Lord. And I did it not of
>   my own accord. That is the interpretation of that about which you
>   could not have patience.

What is the reason of this difference in the three stories ?!

Knowing that all this knowledge from God and his appreciation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this difference is only as literature in general quranic expressions in storytelling, where in the first event said "I intended" and it's a bad business in general, and the second incident in which something of compassion and cruelty, the third incident he stated, "Lord wanted" because it is good work in general.

but I'm not sure if there is a direct cause of this

Comment: Is this your answer or additional question?

Comment: I know this answer, but I am not sure

Comment: But, your answer has more questions. Probably, you can put these questions in main post itself.

Comment: Sorry, You are right 
But the second question is linked to the answer ..
What should I do ?

Comment: I am correct that

Comment: +1 Muhyiddin Ibn Arabi says basically the same thing in Futuhat-Al-Makkiyya. According to the Sufi belief, all actions belong to Allah on their own. However, since actions that are perceived bad/evil cannot be attributed to God, they are attributed to somewhere/something else. Khidr knows when to attribute his actions to God, when to his self and when to both God and his self. This is about the creation of evil and balance of the opposites (yin-yang) which is whole another topic and cannot be explained here thoroughly. But I believe everyone here is able to sense the necessity of evil here.